# Field Value Count

Tags: ee2

Iam having a dropdown field with fixed options.

Let’s say it is {fruits} with options Apple, Pineapple, Banana and Orange

I need to output how many channel entries are there corresponding to each option, next to it.

e.g. 
Apple (10)
Pineapple (20)
Banana (5)
Orange (15)

As you have guessed there are a total of 50 rows for the field {fruits}

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: How are you maintaining a count? If there are 10 apples, is it because there are 10 channel entries with that field set to apple?

Comment: Yes, it is because there are 10 channel entries with value 'Apple' for field {fruits}

Answer (score 1):

Try this? (Not going to be next to an EE install for a few days, can't test):

```
There are
{exp:query sql="SELECT field_id_X as fruit, COUNT(fruit) FROM exp_channel_data GROUP BY fruit" backspace="2"}
{count} {fruit}(s), 
{/exp:query}
```

And you just have to replace field_id_X with the field name from your exp_channel_data table that corresponds to that field.

Comment: Thank you. However, it did not work.

What I wanted to do was this ` {exp:channel:entries channel="items" search:fruits="=Apple"}Apple ({absolute_count}){/exp:channel:entries}`

What is happening is, if there are 3 channel entries for Apples .. it is outputting Apples (3)(3)(3) 

What I need is Apples (3)

Comment: Got it working by this code 
`{exp:query sql="SELECT COUNT(field_id_X) AS fruit FROM exp_channel_data WHERE field_id_X = 'Apples' GROUP BY field_id_X"}({fruit}){/exp:query}` 

Replaced X with the correct number from the table.

Thanks for the heads up @jchrono-battle

Comment: Glad you got it! Yeah, I always have to type SQL queries out a few times at a CLI to get them right, not surprised it needed adjusting.